# Runtime Error em Problema Usando Recursão

Tags: ruby

Eu estou tentando resolver o problema [1030 - Flavious Josephus Legend](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1030), de um site de desafios.

Eu envio o código e diz que tem o erro de Runtime (Acessa uma memória inválida ou array tem pouco espaço):

```
vezes = gets.chomp().to_i
vezes.times do |num|
def jose(n,k) #Fiz o método de maneira correta?
 if (n==0)
    resultado=0  
 else
   return resultado = (( jose(n-1,k)+ k - 1  ) % n)+1 #Eu entendo recursividade, porém acho que fiz errado aqui.
 end
end

phrase=gets.split(" ") #Erro pode estar aqui, não sei fazer de outra maneira que o site aceita a leitura
n=phrase[0].to_i
k=phrase[1].to_i
puts "Case " + (num+1).to_s + ": " + jose(n,k).to_s

end
```

Tem outra maneira de fazer o exercício que o site aceite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja o site esperar as respostas todas juntas no final da execução do programa, e não a cada "enter".

Para resolver isso, uma possível solução é ler os dados todos:

```
vezes.times do
  my_string += gets
end
```

E só tratar essa `string` depois que recebermos o último `input`.

Dê uma olhada numa versão um pouco alterada do seu código:

```
def jose(n,k)
  if (n==0)
    return 0
  else
    return (( jose(n-1,k)+ k - 1  ) % n)+1
  end
end

vezes = gets.chomp().to_i
my_string = ""

vezes.times do
  my_string += gets
end

phrase=my_string.split(" ")
i = 0

phrase.each_slice(2) do |n, k|
  puts "Case " + (i+=1).to_s + ": " + jose(n.to_i,k.to_i).to_s
end
```

[image: resultado de envio da solução]

---

#### Edit:

> O seu método está correto - ele só provavelmente não deveria estar dentro de um loop `do`.

Comment: Fiz um comentário lá em cima no meu código e também o que significa each_slice(2)? Eu sei o que é "each", mas não "slice"...

Comment: @Misaee21 vi sua edição - quanto a ela, duas coisas: errado é uma palavra forte - não, não é errado, mas é necessário? :) e evite editar perguntas já respondidas para incluir novos questionamentos; não existe exatamente um "follow up" de perguntas no SOpt, a não ser quando se cria uma nova - para esclarecer essa e outras dúvidas mais simples, sugiro que você visite [o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: @Misaee21 o `each.slice(n)` te retorna `n` elementos ao invés de apenas um, como no caso do `each`.

Comment: https://i.etsystatic.com/12780725/d/il/3f8d4e/1369912852/il_340x270.1369912852_teyg.jpg